# Clicking on a link hidden based on time

Tags: javascript, timer

Well I am a newbie and i want to know that can I click on a link which is hidden and shows on a particular through **JavaScript on console in Google chrome**. I want to **click on that link before the time it become visible**. I noted its attribute tag when it becomes visible.
I want to click on below attribute tag which become visible on a particular time.

```
<a onclick="aplook(this,'01785','xxxx','xxx','10-12-2014','xx','xx',3);" id="refid2">Click Here </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

The link first needs to load before an action can be perform on it.

You could use CSS to hide the link, and then use javascript to click on it.